Connecting to Oracle SQL Database From Python Without cx-oracle
I need to run a SQL script from python (Jupyter) and need to connect to an existing Oracle database for the same. I am trying to automate the process, as the output of the SQL will serve as input for my statistical modelling code in Jyputer. However, for this, I need to connect to Oracle, but my organization doesn't have the cx_oracle library in the python package. Is there another way to run SQL script from python in Oracle?
I tried using pyodbc as below, but still getting error, although all supplied parameters are correct. The driver I have installed is Oracle in OraClient18Home1_32bit.
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient18Home1};DBQ=sinarrtou01-sc.sg.xx.com:1700/SGART4U_app.sg.xx.com;UID=DASKUMA;PWD=######')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

Error I get is:
InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Did you look at Connect to Oracle with ODBC in Python ?

Are you not allowed to pip/conda install a new package?

@dskmrjt - I'm going to assume that you didn't intend to put what looks to be a real password on a public internet site.  You should probably delete your comment with the password as well.

Agreed @JustinCave, I have deleted the comment. However, I still don't have a resolution to my issue :(

@dskmrjt your choices depend on what you can install/have installed.  They are (1) use python-oracledb, ODBC, or some Python JDBC driver to connect directly to Oracle DB, (2) use an HTTP library to make REST calls to Oracle DB's ORDS server, (3) or call out somehow to a service that you own, where the service connects to the DB via (1) or (2).   My vote is 1, but option 2 is perfectly fine too.

cx-oracle for Python has been deprecated and replaced with python-oracledb
Another alternative would be to be to simply use the requests library to make REST API calls to get your data out of the database.

I have successfully pip installed and used 'oracledb' module to connect to Oracle database from python. Thanks for all the helpful answers and guidance!

Reply using comment on you question instead of using reply :)
